# Foreach loops into streams

Tags: lambda, foreach, java-stream, maps

I have yet another problem with the removal of foreach loops and turning them into streams. I will post the whole method here, in case there is more information needed, than just the foreach loops.
I was already trying to do it with a flatmap, but it does not solve my issue. I hope some of you can help me out! I would gladly appreciate it!

```
public void handlePickedOrders(final List<PickOrder> pickedOrders) {

        Contract.requires(pickedOrders != null, "illegal argument");

        // Your code goes here - if needed

        if (error) {
            new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        }

        if (!pickedOrders.isEmpty()) {
            Map<String, Integer> removedProducts = pickedOrders.stream()
                            .flatMap(n -> n.getPickOrderLines().stream())
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.getProductCode(),
                                    p -> p.getQuantity(),
                                    (a1, a2) -> a1 + a2));
            //Problem area
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : removedProducts.entrySet()) {
                if (error) {
                    System.out.println("Remove " + entry.getValue() + " pieces of " + entry.getKey());
                }
                quantityOnHand.replace(entry.getKey(), quantityOnHand.get(entry.getKey()) - entry.getValue());
            }
            if (error) {
                System.out.println("Remove Pick Orders " + pickedOrders + " from Queue");
            }

            pickOrders.removeAll(pickedOrders);
            for (PickOrder pickOrder : pickOrders) {
                for (String productCode : removedProducts.keySet()) {
                    if (pickOrder.containsProduct(productCode)) {
                        pickOrder.calcReplenishmentsNeeded(quantityOnHand);
                        if (error) {
                            System.out.println("Recalculating: " + pickOrder);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Slow down, re-read your question from the perspective of someone who has not followed your adventures and has no context. Also describing what your issue is might be helpful (error message? something unexpected happens?). Go through the tips in [ask] and [edit] your question afterwards.

Comment: Sorry! The code above is working perfectly fine. I am only in need of turning my foreach loops into streams. There is no error or anything. I only need to turn them into streams.

Answer (score 0):

**Though I have not got the exact problem statement but you may try this kind of nested foreach loop that might you are looking for.
I hope it will help you out.**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<PickOrder> pickedOrders = Arrays.asList(
           new PickOrder("pc1",1000),
           new PickOrder("pc2",2000),
           new PickOrder("pc3",3000),
           new PickOrder("pc4",4000),
           new PickOrder("pc5",5000)
        );

        List<PickOrder> pickOrders = Arrays.asList(
                new PickOrder("pc6",6000),
                new PickOrder("pc7",7000),
                new PickOrder("pc8",8000)
        );

        Map<String, Integer> removedProducts = new HashMap<>();
        removedProducts.put("pc1",1000);
        removedProducts.put("pc2",2000);
        removedProducts.put("pc3",3000);

        pickOrders.forEach( pickOrder -> removedProducts.keySet().forEach(rp -> {
            if(pickOrder.getProductCode().equals(rp)) {
                //pickOrder.calcReplenishmentsNeeded(quantityOnHand);
                /*if (error) {
                    System.out.println("Recalculating: " + pickOrder);
                }*/
            }
        }));
    }
```

**PickOrder.java**

```
public class PickOrder {

    private String productCode;
    private int quantity;

    public PickOrder(String productCode, int quantity) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }

    public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

**Thanks**
*Girdhar*